# My Code on Pygame is not working

Tags: python, math, pygame

I need help. My code is not working on Pygame. All that it shows is a blank screen. My code is supposed to ask you for a number, then when you enter it, the code displays that number to the power of three. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption('Cube')

gameExit = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)

def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])


while not gameExit:
    def input(number):
        message_to_screen("Enter a Number to Cube")
        total = number ** 3
        if number > 0: 
            message_to_screen(total, red)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()

time.sleep(2)
if gameExit == True:
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: The `while not gameExit` looks suspicious. Could be an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I notice:

- You fill your gameDisplay with white, prior to updating it. This means that everything you drew before is overwritten.
- The function `input` is never called
- The function `input` is being defined in the while-loop. It would be wise to take it out.
- The check on `gameExit` == True is never reached within your while loop. Move it inside the loop.

Those are all some pretty basic errors. Are you aware of what you're doing and is there some tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the screen is blank is because you're filling it with a solid color just before updating.

```
while not gameExit:
    def input(number):
        message_to_screen("Enter a Number to Cube")
        total = number ** 3
        if number > 0: 
            message_to_screen(total, red)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)  # <-- THIS OVERDRAWS EVERYTHING ELSE
    pygame.display.update()
```